# Cannot find module '@ionic-native/speech-recognition'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have installed:

`npm install @ionic-native/core --save
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-speechrecognition  --save`

and I can even see it in package.json but when I am adding it in `app.module.ts` I am getting this error:

> Cannot find module '@ionic-native/speech-recognition'

I do not understand what to do, I have removed it and added it many times but nothing is working.

My `package.json` code is below

```
{
  "name": "quicktask",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^0.1.24",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.11",
    "cordova-plugin-speechrecognition": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.1.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.8.0",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.2.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-speechrecognition": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please Find Solved Already : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54365080/3725226

Comment: I Faced Same Situation Due To Update Version [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54365080/3725226)

Answer (score 2):

As per the docs, [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/speech-recognition/), you will need to run npm install --save @ionic-native/speech-recognition in addition to installing the cordova plugin